# Store notes within folders (alternative Dropbox Paper)

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization, notes.app, dropbox

I would like to store a note or text document within a finder folder and have that sync across all my devices and my wife's devices. And be accessed from the note/text app itself. This is currently totally possible with Dropbox Paper, but Dropbox Paper is slow. I'm looking for something as simple and quick as Apple Notes.

As I use Google Drive and Dropbox I can effectively chuck any text file into a folder and it will sync, but I'm looking for something that can be accessed from within a folder and from the app itself. And I repeat, Dropbox Paper does all this but it is slow and I find myself randomly switching to Notes app when I'm in a hurry.

Thanks,

Grant

Comment: OneDrive does this seamlessly and very quickly. In fact, I use it over iCloud to sync documents.  But for Notes, the app you want is OneNote.  You can easily share single pages or even whole notebooks.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Looks like OneNote doesn't save the files locally it just saves a link, which when opened from Finder opens the web version of OneNote not the desktop app. And as well you can't choose a folder to save it to. Let me know if I have got that wrong. Dropbox Paper saves an actually application file, which opens in the Dropbox Paper desktop app (like opening a word doc), but like I said it's slow to open and slow to create notes. However today I found Outline, which (yes!) saves the notes locally and syncs them as well. It's not free though. And it's compatible with OneNote. Thanks!